# Shiny:Reactive SQL queries (output of 1st query as input of 2nd query)

Tags: sql, r, shiny, roracle

is it possible to have 2 SQL queries, and take the output of 1st of them as an input of the 2nd?

What i meant, I would like use the first SQL query, maybe smthg like this?:

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "Select distinct X From K.Tabelle order by X asc")
data <- fetch(rs)
```

Therefore i could get a list of uniqe values from column X. Further I would like to use this list as a choice in `selectInput("select1",...)` widget of `shiny` **(and it would be great if i could as well have a choice to get all of the values)**, which will be further used in the second/final query:

```
query <- reactive( sprintf("select * from K.Tabelle",
                               " where", input$tablename, "=", input$select1, sep="")
```

Is it possible? I have no idea where i should put the first query? On the server side as well?

My code:

```
library(ROracle)
library(shiny)

get_data <- 
  function(query){
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(con)) ## important to close connection
    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xx",username="user",password="pwd")
    dbGetQuery(con,query)
  }

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    query <-  reactive( sprintf("select * from K.Tabelle",
                               " where", input$tablename, "=", input$select1, sep="")
    ## simply  displaying reactive inputs
    output$table <- renderTable(
     get_data(query())
    )
  })

ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Test",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tableOutput("table")
             )
           )
  )


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",ui_panel))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Thanks for the tipps

Comment: hey, should i use this function:`session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })` on the server side? P.S. When i have used the  `tabellen <- dbListTables(con, schema="K")` on the server side, it gave an error `Error in dbListTables(con, schema = "K") : 
  Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'conn' bei der Methodenauswahl
für Funktion 'dbListTables': Fehler: Objekt 'con' nicht gefunden` (Object 'con' has not been found), this means i cannot use `con` to get additionally data/or to use it for second query?

Comment: I actually did it, but before i wrapped it in the function `eventReactive` for the action Button: `connectDB <- eventReactive(input$connectDB, {
    
    if(input$drv != "Oracle"){
      stop("Only 'Oracle' implemented currently")
    }else{
      drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
    }
   
    con <- dbConnect(drv,"xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/K",username=input$user,password=input$passwd) 
    con
  })`

Comment: I even tried on the simple example Your code: `server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {   
    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xx",username="user",password="pwd")
    session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) }) 
    tabellen <- dbListTables(con, schema="K")})`, and it is not working, again: `Object 'con' has not been found`

Comment: where error (on which statement `dbDisconnect(con)` or `dbListTables(con, schema="K")`) ?  for me it works....

Comment: `dbListTables(con, schema="K")`

Comment: try debug and find error.. for example 1) print con `library(ROracle)
ui=fluidPage()
server <- shinyServer( function(input, output, session){
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xx",username="user",password="pwd") 
session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })
observe({print(con)})
})
shinyApp(server = server,ui = ui)`

Comment: Hey, I have no idea why it didnt work. I have tried it again, smthg like: `server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xxx/K",username="user",password="pwd")
    tableList <- dbListTables(con,schema="K")
    output$out <- renderPrint(tableList) 
    session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })
  })` and it is working